# Predicting percentiles with percentile data

Tags: regression, quantiles, quantile-regression

I have a few independent variables and 5 dependent(target) variables. The target variables are percentiles (10th, 25th, 50th, 75th, 90th) and I want to predict the same in that order. What approach would best suit the problem? Would quantile regression be suitable for the kind of data I have? So far from what I have read, I haven't come across any approach where quantile regression is being used with a set of percentiles as dependent variables. I am kind of new to this so I am still exploring things a bit. Any other approach that would be suitable?